# How to match web api 2 route with forward slashes in request parameters?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm using Web API 2 attribute routing and I have a request which is not resolved properly.

```
[Route("~/foo/{bar?}")]
public void Get(string bar);
```

My request it's like: *mydomain.me/foo/abc/def*

I expect to receive bar as "abc/def" but the forward slash messes the route match.
Replacing the forward slash with "%2F" doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could use wildcard based matching like below:

```
[Route("~/foo/{*bar}")]
public string Get(string bar)
```

Comment: Just by way of note: calling it "wildcard based matching" makes it sound like a whole different way of matching.  It's not.  It's literally just adding a parameter on the end of a route, beginning with a star, to match forward slashes too.

Comment: also point to be considered while using this approach is that, it will fit if route has only one parameter whose value can contain "/", further that parameter shall be at end in route. but if there are multiple parameters with probability of having "/" in their value or even with single parameter if that can't be put in last of route/url, then also it would not work/fit.

Comment: Works nicely for me