# ASP.NET Core MVC: Problem with routing argument that contains %2F (forward slash)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following routing attribute in place:

```
[HttpGet("{id}/foo")]
```

My id is a base64 encoded value, and, as such, may contain a forward slash. I'm encoding this forward slash using `%2F`, however, it seems like ASP.NET Core MVC decodes the URL, *then* matches routes, as I'm getting a 404 if my `id` contains `%2F`.

Is there any way I can allow `%2F` in my `id`?

I know there are some answers out there (e.g. [How to match web api 2 route with forward slashes in request parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034227/how-to-match-web-api-2-route-with-forward-slashes-in-request-parameters)), but with all of them, the parameter in question, is always the last, and only then you can use a wildcard (?).

Comment: Maybe dare to try ASP.NET Core 2.2-preview3? See [ASP.NET Core 2.2-preview3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/10/17/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview3-now-available/) blog in the Routing section for the new `slugify` routes. Not sure it works for incoming routes, but will for sure work with Url generation

Comment: Sorry, wrong article. It's [ASP.NET Core 2.2-preview1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/08/27/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview1-endpoint-routing/) about the new Endpoint Routing, look down to "New round-tripping route parameter syntax".

Comment: Hey, I have the same issue, using AspNetCore 2.2

Comment: same issue with .net core 3.1

Comment: I know it's dirty, but why not simply replace all forward slashes with a character that isn't in the Base64 alphabet (such as a underscore) and then replace them with forward slashes in the receiving controller?

Comment: for those who found this from Google, here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30994100/553073) that could be helpful. basically encode the input twice, and decode it properly in the server side.